# Android RelativeLayout above Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-relativelayout, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to display a RelativeLayout above a Fragment without success.

And here my xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#5C5A59"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:background="#5C5A59"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_altitude"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/lbl_altitude"
            android:textColor="#00FFFF"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Using this code the Fragment takes always the entire size of the screen and my RelativeLayout above isnt display.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `layout_weight` property

You can read this guide: [Linear Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the Linear layout then you have to set the weight this will set your screen according to the percentage for example if you give weightsum 1 to the parent and then you first give the layout weight 0.2 to your layout ang 0.8 to your fragement its means your layout acquires the 20% screen and other  fragement acquire 80%

So i think you want to use the Relative layout as your parent and set first child aligment on the top of parent and set the fragement below to the relative layout.